# How to Send different Id on the same page using List in php

Tags: php

Hello I am working on one php project in which i am having a menu. I am having a single page which will display the data of every item according to their ID
my query is how can i send my id from menu to that Page
Here Is my code for menu

```
    <?php
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("Test");
        $sql=mysql_query("select * from Menu");
        echo '<ul>';
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            echo "<a href='sample.php'><li> . $row['name'] . "</li></a>"; 
        }
    ?>
```

Every menu Item has it's own name and Id I want to send Id of every menu item to sample.php

Please help

Comment: So you want to send the ID to to the "sample.php" page?

Comment: The usual generic hint: you are using phps deprecated and outdated `mysql` extension. You should switch to `mysqli` instead or `PDO`.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
echo "<a href='sample.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "'><li>" . $row['name'] . "</li></a>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("Test");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from Menu");
echo '<ul>';
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
     echo "<a href='sample.php?id=". $row['id'] . "><li> ". $row['name'] . "</li></a>"; 
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
echo "<a href='sample.php?id=".$row['id']."'><li> ". $row['name'] . "</li></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
echo "<a href='sample.php?id=".$row['id']."'><li>" . $row['name'] . "</li></a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $row['id'] and $row['name']

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
 echo "<a href='sample.php?id=". $row['id'] . "><li> ". $row['name'] . "</li>< /a>"; 
}
```

Comment: How Does this provide anything that hasn't all ready been provided in the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<ul>
<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
     echo "<li><a href='sample.php?id=". $row['id'] . "'> ". $row['name'] . "</a></li>"; 
}?>
</ul>
```

wraping anchor tag in a 'li' tag is not a proper method in html